# vba incrementing a range's row

Tags: vba, excel

this should be a really quick question.

Is there any way to increment the value of a cell.Row?
For example, can I say something like usedCell.Row = usedCell.Row + 1?

That particular format doesn't work, but is there another way to increase the row by 1?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Row` and `Column` properties of a cell (i.e. `Range`) are read-only so you can't increment them directly.

If you want to move through the cells in column A then iDevlop's answer works fine. An alternative method is to use the `Cells` method of the `Worksheet` object. Example code to write the word "hello" into every cell in column A from row 1 to 100:

```
Dim lRow As Long

For lRow = 1 To 100
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(lRow, 1).Value = "hello"
Next lRow
```

As you can see in the example, the `Cells` method takes the row number as the first parameter and the column number as the second parameter.

For the simple case of dealing with cells in the same column, you could also use the `Range` property of the `Worksheet` object and construct the actual address - e.g. A39 - each time:

```
Dim lRow As Long

For lRow = 1 To 100
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & lRow).Value = "hello"
Next lRow
```

Answer (score 10):

I believe `cell.Offset(1,0)` is what you are looking for.

Comment: Ok so that seems like it will work for the row, but when I increment the row, I need to statically set the column to the first column of the spreadsheet.

So if I say rngUsedCell = rngUsedCell.Offset(1,0) that should move it down one row, but the phrase rngUsedCell.Column = 1 did not seem to work.

Comment: Offset is a relative function. It points to rows / columns based on the current cell position; therefore, offset(1,1) would point to the cell one row below, one column after the current cell. On the other way round, offset(-1,-1) points to a row above, one column before the current cell. Improve your question, and we can give you better answers. Still, for the question you made, offset is the answer, and for this, +1.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using

```
Dim c as Range
For Each c in Range("a:a")
    ...
Next c
```

?

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking for

Set rng = rng.Resize(RowSize, ColumnSize)

In your case specifically

```
Dim rng_usedCells As Range

Set rng_usedCells = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:B10")

ActiveSheet.Range("D2").Value = rng_usedCells.Rows.Count
ActiveSheet.Range("E2").Value = rng_usedCells.Columns.Count

Set rng_usedCells = rng_usedCells.Resize(3, 4)

ActiveSheet.Range("D3").Value = rng_usedCells.Rows.Count
ActiveSheet.Range("E3").Value = rng_usedCells.Columns.Count
```

[image: rng.Resize]